# Installing APT packages to versioned directories

Tags: apt

Is it possible to get APT to install different versions of a packages to different versioned directories?

Like:

```
/usr/share/tomcat-7.0.64
/usr/share/tomcat-7.0.65
/usr/share/tomcat-8.0.29
/usr/share/tomcat-8.0.30
```

And just create the following symlink to whichever I want to use at the moment?

```
/usr/share/tomcat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general packages have one version installed, unless the package maintainer did something clever. (They also cannot be relocated to a different path without rebuilding the package. RPM can sort of do a relocate but very few use it.)

Debian 8 has [tomcat7](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/tomcat7/filelist) and tomcat8 as different package names. These should coexist by appending 7 or 8 to everything, but you do not specify the minor version.

If you require versions not provided by your distro, you could skip the package.  Put what you require in /opt or somewhere. Note that then you take responsibility for updates (beyond just aptitude upgrade).

Comment: Thanks.  Not the answer I wanted, but the answer I suspected...  Too bad APT doesn't support this.